# singleton class to return two instances only expressjs

Tags: typescript, express

I have a `Player` class and an `initPlayers` middleware. I'm trying to make two player instances so that I could track their scores in a simple rock, paper, scissors game.

```
export class Player {
  _score: number;
  private static instance: Player;
  constructor() {
    this._score = 0;
    Player.instance = this;
  }

  addPoint() {
    this._score += 1;
  }

  static getInstance() {
    if (!Player.instance) {
      Player.instance = new Player();
    }
    return Player.instance;
  }
}
```

```
export class Game {
  ruleSet: IRuleSet[];
  player1: Player;
  player2: Player;
  constructor(player1: Player, player2: Player) {
    this.player1 = player1;
    this.player2 = player2;
    this.ruleSet = ruleSet;
  }

  whoWins(player1Choice: string, player2Choice: string): { message: string } {
    console.log(player1Choice, player2Choice);
    for (const [_, rule] of ruleSet.entries()) {
      if (player1Choice == rule.choice) {
        if (rule.losesTo.includes(player2Choice)) {
          this.player2.addPoint();
          return {
            message: `Player 2 Wins with ${player2Choice}`,
          };
        } else if (rule.beats.includes(player2Choice)) {
          this.player1.addPoint();
          return {
            message: `Player 1 Wins with ${player1Choice}`,
          };
        } else {
          return {
            message: 'Draw',
          };
        }
      }
    }

    // Return a default value if no match is found
    return {
      message: 'Invalid Choice',
    };
  }
}
```

```
// controller
  public play(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { player1Move, player2Move, player1, player2 } = req.body;
    const game = new Game(player1, player2);
    const result = game.whoWins(player1Move, player2Move);

    console.log('SCORES', player1._score, player2._score); 
    res.render('game', {
      data: req.body,
      player1Score: player1.score,
      player2Score: player2.score,
    });
  }
```

```
// middleware to run before route handler which is play()
export const initPlayers = (req: Request, _: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  req.body = {
    ...req.body,
    player1: Player.getInstance(),
    player2: Player.getInstance(),
  };
  next();
};
```

upon winning of a player, both scores gets incremented. this is because ofcourse, both players are pointing to the same instance. i'm thinking how to fix this in order to increment the scores separately for each player after winning.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to set this up is to store two instances of `Player` in the `Player` class, and retrieve them via `getFirstInstance()` and `getSecondInstance()` or similar methods:

```
export class Player {
  _score: number;
  private static instance1: Player;
  private static instance2: Player;
  constructor() {
    this._score = 0;
  }

  addPoint() {
    this._score += 1;
  }

  static getFirstInstance() {
    if (!Player.instance1) {
      Player.instance1 = new Player();
    }
    return Player.instance1;
  }

  static getSecondInstance() {
    if (!Player.instance2) {
      Player.instance2 = new Player();
    }
    return Player.instance2;
  }
}
```

However, this is not good practice and the pattern is not going to be reliable and extensible in the long-term. Instead you can store the players in a separate object that handles the initialisation as well, and can have other related methods like a way to reset the scores.

Here's an example, where you can call the constructor to set up or retrieve your current players, and use `resetState()` to get a pair of new players as necessary. In this example you wouldn't want to use a singleton pattern for the Player class, and instead have a simple object that holds a score and has an `addPoint()` method.

```
export class State {
  private static _player1: Player;
  private static _player2: Player;
  constructor() {
    return this.getState();
  }

  getState() {
    if (!State._player1 || !State._player2) {
      State._player1 = new Player();
      State._player2 = new Player();
    }
    return this;
  }

  resetState() {
    State._player1 = undefined;
    State._player2 = undefined;
  }
}
```

Also consider setting up a context object to pass the values from the middleware to the game, rather than adding them to the request body.

Comment: thanks but what do you mean to store the players in a separate object? can you elaborate a bit, please ?

Comment: @ExodusReed I've added an example to the answer.